# What security concerns exist in running a glassfish app directly on port 443

Tags: tls, webserver, java, apache, ports

I have installed Apache http server in front of glassfish based on recommendations i had in this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/413108/is-it-bad-practice-to-run-a-glassfish-app-directly-on-port-80-443).

I have been told that i will run into performance problems along with **security issues**. I was able to make Apache handle port 80 connections.
However i had some problems concerning https, see my [Other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/413789/apache-in-front-of-glassfish-mod-jk-on-https443).

Now that my application itself directs to Https (using CONFIDENTIAL in web.xml) and not apache, is there a security issue if i make glassfish run its http-listener-2 on port 443 directly?

What is happening now is:

- i type: www.adomain.com
- since application runs on root context, url becomes: https://www.adomain.com:8181

**so the flow is: www.adomain.com:80 --> Apache --> Glassfish root context app (app forces https)**

i do **not** want to show the port 8181 in the url. I tried several methods (mod_rewrite, disabling port 80 so that only 443 runs,etc..) but nothing was working.

If i set http-listener-2 in glassfish to run on 443, port 8181 won't show in the URL.

I have no experience in server admin and it's beyond my expertise, but since this is a personal project i have to do the server tasks.

Excuse my maybe basic question but how **unsecure** is it to run directly on port 443 and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your Java app to work in e.g. context like http://www.example.com/something/ on port 80 on the local ip number e.g. 127.0.0.1 and apache listening on public ip 1.2.3.4 port 80 and forwarding the requests to the 127.0.0.1 and even without /something you should not have issues.

You can drop mod_security to apache to even further improve security.

Comment: do you know any good tutorial for apache forwarding to localhost's 8181 port?(i have no experience with apache at all and i am not knowing how to make this work)

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass this is all you need